# Email field is not getting reset while assigning blank object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing problem while resetting form in angular.

**HTML**

```
<form name="jay" novalidate class="simple-form">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
      E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
      Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
      <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
      <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
      <button ng-click="update(user)">SAVE</button>
    </form>
    <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
    <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        //$scope.masterReset = {email:""};
        $scope.masterReset = {};
        $scope.master = {};

        $scope.update = function(user) {
          $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.user);
        };

        $scope.reset = function() {
          $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.masterReset);
          //console.log($scope.jay);
        };

        $scope.reset();
      }]);
```

**Try below steps**

**Step 1 -** Fill the details in form as Abc, xyz and select male or female.

**Step 2 -** Now click on reset. You can see email textbox is not getting blank because we have entered wrong value in email. Now try entering email in correct format then click on Reset, it will reset all 3 fields.

Plunker - [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cPo1j2FoZhLDvFyLfLDY?p=preview)

**It works with below but can't use it**

If we set `$scope.masterReset` object with `email` property as blank then it works fine but I want blank object when user has not fill any details. Also I can iterate over the object and remove which is blank but I have many fields in my form so I don't want to do that.

Suggest me why it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Force User to enter correct email address by following code `ng-disabled="jay.$invalid"`  See the [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/FNWH0lyyFgMJGZ3Y61k4?p=preview)

```
<form name="jay" novalidate class="simple-form">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
  Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
  <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
  <button ng-disabled="jay.$invalid" ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
  <button ng-disabled="jay.$invalid" ng-click="update(user)">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

It did not work because when you write incomplete email address it triggers a validation error. So if you implement validation and force user to complete email address then you can keep input type to "email".

Comment: I can't change email to text because I want to validate email too.

Comment: I have this kind of alternate solution and thanks for this but what I want to know is why it's not resetting. I want to understand what angular does exactly. So I can't accept it as this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that is happening is because the email is not being set for user object in the `$scope`.
This is because when you set the `input` type to email, `angularjs` sets email validations to the field. Now if you try with a regular email then the code works as expected.

For example: abc@xyz.com

Here's a reference to the link
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D

Comment: I know this is the problem but I want to fix it by using input type email only.